# How to find nature of RLC circuit?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, inductor, passive-networks, homework

If a resistance value, XL value and XC value are given, how do we determine the nature of the circuit (whether it's capacitive, resistive or inductive)?

The only thing that comes to my mind looking at the 3 given values is the impedance.

Is there any specific formula or any other way how to tell?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given a load, how do you calculate whether it is capacitive or inductive?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/130962/given-a-load-how-do-you-calculate-whether-it-is-capacitive-or-inductive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying resistive, capacitive, or inductive just means which behaviour is dominant. It's not a precise term and one of those things students might try too hard to ascribe precise formal definition to when it is inappropriate. In my opinion it is rather unimportant. Things are what they are with varying shades of grey.

So just combine Xc and XL since they oppose each other (whether parallel or series) to get the net  reactance. Capacitive reactance are negative and inductive reactance is positive so whatever sign your result has tells you the net effect. That's precise.

It can only be considered resistive if the resistance is much larger than the net reactance to the point where the net reactance is negligible. That's not so precise.

In practice it's pretty obvious what you have when the machine is in front of you taking measurements and have more than numbers on a piece of paper that someone made up.

Comment: A good practical assessment.